# If part of cell match variable then

Tags: if-statement, excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how I could write an if-statement so that if a variable matches part of cell then the condition is met and the script runs.

E.g.

A1 contains "aa ss dd"

A2 contains "dd ss dd"

A3 contains "aa"

The variable v = aa

Currently I have a statement that matches the the entire cell:

If ActiveCell.Value = v Then
   ...

With this code A3 meet the condition but I want A1 to match it as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, v) Then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MatchPartOfCell()
    Dim sSearch As String
    Dim rng As Range

    sSearch = "aa"
    Set rng = Range("A1")

    Do Until rng = ""
    If InStr(rng.Value, sSearch) > 0 Then
        rng.Offset(, 1).Value = "I contain aa."
    End If
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub
```